# How is redux thunk with extra argument working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, server-side-rendering, redux-thunk

this is the source code of redux-thunk library:

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

export default thunk;
```

I can not understand how "thunk" and "thunk.withExtraArguent" are different from each other.

`const thunk=createThunkMiddleware()` // this is the middleware that we use for our async requests

However thunk.withExtraArgument is the SAME createThunkMiddleware function but this time it is just being passed as a reference. We are able to pass an argument  here but we cannot pass the argument to the **thunk**.

Can someone explain the difference please? To me **thunk** and **thunk.withExtraArgument** are same

Comment: It does seems you already know the difference... one is a middleware with the extra argument undefined, the other is a function that you yourself can invoke to create such middleware with an extra argument. What's not clear?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what the question is here

Comment: @DanPantry To me **thunk** and **thunk.withExtraArgument** look same

Comment: Document about [thunk. withExtraArgument](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my universal javascript app, I created axios instance and redux store on the client and server. I pass the client-side axios instance to the client-side store and server-side axios instance to the server-side store.

Since reducers are supposed to be “pure” (they don’t change anything outside their scope) we can’t do any API calls or dispatch actions from inside a reducer. If you want an action to do something, that code needs to live inside a function. Normally our actions are just plain objects, we just dispatch them to the reducer directly. Redux-thunk is a middleware that looks at every action that passes through the system, and if it’s a function, it calls that function. Redux will pass two arguments to thunk functions: **dispatch**, so that they can dispatch new actions if they need to; and **getState**, so they can access the current state. REdux-thunk middleware gives us the ability for an action creator to return a function instead of an action object. However extraArgument is not defined with thunk function.

```
  const thunk = createThunkMiddleware()
```

When I created each of redux store copies, I also created a custom instance of axios and pass that custom instance into redux thunk as an extra third argument. Then in our action creators whenever I make some type of network request, I receive the customized copy of axios rather than the actual module itself. Then I can make request without actually worry about whether we are on the client or on the server. `thunk.withExtraArgument` is the middleware that extra argument is defined. So I use the thunk.withExtraArgument and pass the axios instances.

#### Side Note:

`thunk` is a fancy name for a function that is used to delay a calculation until results are needed

Answer (score 0):

you can add an Extra redux-thunk param as a function reference and call it in your async actions.
you can read more about [how to use Axios as an ExtraParameter](https://medium.com/@saphidev/redux-in-react-and-combining-with-axios-94a2adfbeeb) in this story on Medium